# Informatica Expression IS_DATE

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

This works:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('12'|| '-' || '12' || '-01'),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

This does not work:

```
IS_DATE(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('12'|| '-' || '12' || '-01'),'YYYY/MM/DD'))
IS_DATE(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('12'|| '-' || '12' || '-01'),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?
I have tried datatypes `STRING` and `DATE/TIME`

Comment: "Doesn't work" . What's not working ??

Comment: IS_DATE is not working and does not validate if  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('12'|| '-' || '12' || '-01'),'YYYY/MM/DD') is a date or not

Comment: Does it throw an error? Does it throw bad output? What does it do wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, it states "invalid operand datatype"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

IS_DATE(TO_CHAR('12'|| '-' || '12' || '-01'),'YYYY/MM/DD')

Syntax:
IS_DATE(input as char,format as char)

IS_DATE returns 1 if the input is a valid date and 0 if the date is not valid.

IS_DATE('02/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')-> returns 1
IS_DATE('02312013','MMDDYYYY')-> returns 0(as February 31st is not a valid date)